# Linux redirectors not logging errors. Does Linux have the equivalent to Windows' 2>&1?

Tags: linux, redirection

I run the following file with the `> log.log` redirector, and it does not capture errors.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ************************BEGIN LOG******************************
date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S $HOSTNAME"
cp -f /scripts/original/clamscans.log /scripts
find /public/public/clamscans/. -exec grep -n FOUND /dev/null {} \;>>clamscans.log
mail somedude@someplace.com < clamscans.log
tar cvf dailyresults.tar /public/public/clamscans/*.txt
gzip -f dailyresults.tar
mv -f /public/public/clamscans/*.txt /scripts/lastnite
echo end log entry
```

The following errors show up when I run from the file from the terminal window, but they are not written to `log.log`:

```
tar: /public/public/clamscans/*.txt: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
mv: cannot stat `/public/public/clamscans/*.txt': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? I know with Windows you can add the `2>&1` to capture error data. Is there such a thing for Linux?

Comment: `command &> filename` to redirect both stdout and stderr to file named `filename`.

Comment: I think it is Windows that at some point got redirection similar to what is available in the UNIX shell, not vice versa.

Comment: The funny thing is I had no idea `2>&1` worked on windows, so I thought I read the question wrong at first.  Moral of the story:  sometimes the equivalent in the other OS is identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File descriptor 1 is stdout, 2 is stderr. This applies to both Linux and Windows. With ">logfile", you're redirecting stdout to the file "logfile", but what you actually want is to redirect stderr. That can be done with "2>filename" or "2>&1" (in combination with ">logfile") on both Windows and Linux, but note that the order might be significant, so it should be "command >logfile 2>&1" and not the other way round.

Comment: I foolishly assumed it couldn't be that easy. Yet, it works just like Windows. I'm surprised someone didn't flame me for this. Hope I didn't just give somebody an idea either... Thanks.

Comment: At least one difference remains, i.e. when you want to discard stderr. With Unix you do `2>/dev/null` while with Windows you do `2>nul` - unless you're using `cygwin` or others.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect standard error to a file like this:

```
mycommand 2> error.log
```

and you can use the following syntax to [redirect both standard output and standard error](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/) to a file:

```
mycommand &> file
```

or

```
mycommand > file-name 2>&1
```